# Google Auth - Can I persist user consent between auth sessions?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, single-sign-on

I am trying to figure out whether I can persist user consent to e.g. access the User's calendar or Users inbox between log in.

Overview of the ideal auth flow:

1. User creates the account using SSO
2. I do request consent to access Gmail Account
3. (If Granted) I keep user logged in using Token Revocation, and I do operate based on the scope provided in the token from the Account Creation
4. (After user logs out / token refresh token expires) they will log in again using SSO - Ideally I would not ask for the consent to access mailbox at this point only the User Account selection.

Question: Is persisting this initial consent to access mailbox legal / possible at all between session? If yes how do I go about persisting this initial consent to access mailbox? Or I would need to request consent again as I need it encrypted in token to access the resources?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of application are you working with? (add on, client-side webapp, etc), is it your intention to just simplify the login flow to the users? and just to be clear, what's the current behavior your users are experiencing when logging out?.

Comment: Yes, you can save/store the OAuth Refresh Token which persists for days/weeks. However, review the documentation. If your app uses certain scopes, such as the ones you require, your application might require an audit. [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/production-readiness/restricted-scope-verification)

Comment: @MilagroSosa application type: webapp and mobile app. Yes, it is to simplify the login flow. Logging out would basically clear the session/tokens. User needs to authenticate through Google again but Ideally no user consent step to access Gmail once it was granted. I would like to retain that consent until it's manually 'Forgotten' by the user from the dashboard/deleting account.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for the advice with the audit. Page that you have linked mention that the Gmail scope is restricted. One of the requirements include:Transfers of data are not allowed, except:To provide or improve your appropriate access or user-facing features that are visible and prominent in the requesting application's user interface and only with the user's consent. Does the transfer of data refers to saving it to Cloud Storage e.g. / DB? I am not planning on storing email but some data derived from them.

Comment: The key is that your app is accessing redistricted data. Where you store it is not a factor (I think). Note: Limit your post to one question. For each question you have, post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by [@JohnHanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)

> “Yes, you can save/store the OAuth Refresh Token which persists for
> days/weeks”

And I would like to elaborate more about this. You can store tokens in browser local storage. This should minimize the entire ‘sign-in’ flow for your users. According to the Google Oauth documentation, there is a section showing an example of how to store the token:

```
 var YOUR_CLIENT_ID = 'REPLACE_THIS_VALUE'; 
 var YOUR_REDIRECT_URI = 'REPLACE_THIS_VALUE';
 var fragmentString = location.hash.substring(1); 

// Parse query string to see if page request is coming from OAuth 2.0 server

  var params = {};
  var regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
  while (m = regex.exec(fragmentString)) {
    params[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
  }
  if (Object.keys(params).length > 0) {
    localStorage.setItem('oauth2-test-params', JSON.stringify(params) );
    if (params['state'] && params['state'] == 'try_sample_request') {
      trySampleRequest();
    }
  }
```

The complete example can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#example)

While looking for documentation to share with you I came across [this article about the alternative of using cookies to store OAuth tokens securely](https://medium.com/@sadnub/simple-and-secure-api-authentication-for-spas-e46bcea592ad).